# Como verificar se uma view existe antes de mandar criá-la?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Tome como exemplo a seguinte view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_types AS
SELECT
    codigo AS code,
    nome AS description,
    abreviacao AS abbreviation,
    statusRegistro AS status
FROM 
    tipos
```

Como posso mandar criá-la apenas se a mesma não existir na base de dados?

Comment: acredito que a melhor aproximação seria aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/639127/1739930 já que CREATE VIEW deve ser a única instrução de um lote fica difícil colocá-la dentro de um `IF OBJECT_ID('vw_types ') IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você não deseja alterar ou deletar a View que já existe, basta checar se ela existe, caso exista realize alguma ação ou não faça nada.

```
      IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM sys.views v
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on v.schema_id = s.schema_id
        WHERE s.name = 'dbo' and v.name = 'vw_types'
    )
        EXEC sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE VIEW vw_types AS
SELECT
    codigo AS code,
    nome AS description,
    abreviacao AS abbreviation,
    statusRegistro AS status
FROM 
    tipos;' ;
ELSE
        print 'ja exixte uma view com esse nome'
GO
```

Neste caso eu estou apenas trazendo uma mensagem informando que ela já existe no `ELSE print 'ja exixte uma view com esse nome'`, mas isto é opcional. Você pode excluir, ou mandar fazer outra ação.